# tableau embedded code is giving 401 error

Tags: tableau-api

we trying to show tableau site view in our website using by OAuth 2.0 Trust.but its showing (HTTP) 401 Unauthorized in [v1 signin api](https://prod-uk-a.online.tableau.com/vizportal/api/web/v1/auth/embed/signin). but i am not getting any solution for solve this issue.

We are use OAuth 2.0 Trust Document url - https://help.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/connected_apps_eas.htm
and we also create connected app and getting information which is required for create jwt token
[image]
we create Programmatically jwt token for authentication and pass jwt token in embedded code.
but its show (HTTP) 401 Unauthorized response.
we use embedded code Example is -

```
<tableau-viz id="tableauViz"
  src='https://your-tableau-server/views/my-workbook/my-view'
  token="JWT generated from connected app secrets">
</tableau-viz>
```

embedded code is use this api url  - https://prod-uk-a.online.tableau.com/vizportal/api/web/v1/auth/embed/signin
Api response is

```
{
    "result": {
        "customization": {
            "serverName": "Tableau Cloud"
        },
        "preloginCustomization": {
            "resetPasswordUrl": "https://id.tableau.com/user/resetPassword",
            "preloginNotificationImgUrl": "https://cdns.tblsft.com/sites/default/files/snippets/400x250_90_ad.jpg",
            "preloginNotificationImgLink": "https://www.tableau.com/new-features/9.0"
        },
        "wgEnabled": false,
        "dsdPhoneSize": 500,
        "dsdTabletSize": 800,
        "hideAdminVizStatsForLoadTimes": true,
        "hideAdminVizPerformanceOfViews": true,
        "signInNoteText": "",
        "signInNoteUrl": "",
        "enableDeepLinking": true,
        "product": "TableauOnline",
        "identityPoolsEnabled": false,
        "domainFamily": "external",
        "passwordResetEnabled": false,
        "guestEnabled": false,
        "defaultLanguage": "en_GB",
        "embeddedVizForSiteSamlSupported": true,
        "siteSamlEnabled": true,
        "connectedClientsVisible": true,
        "tableauIdSupported": true,
        "ldapStore": false,
        "desktopSamlDisabled": false,
        "signInNoteEnabled": true,
        "authenticationType": {
            "type": "SAML"
        },
        "bridgeEnabled": true,
        "defaultLocale": "en_GB",
        "samlServiceEntityId": "https://sso.online.tableau.com/public/idp/metadata"
    }
}
```

Please guide me for solve this issue.
Thanks in advance